# Fontawesome icons don't show in IE8 and Chrome (Windows only)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, google-chrome, heroku, font-awesome

I'm running into a problem with a Rails app I'm building. I'm using fontawesome to render a few icons. The rails app is running on Heroku.

The problem is that on Chrome/Win and IE8, the icons are not rendered. No box - nothing. They render in IE9, Firefox/Win, and they render on all browsers in OS X.

I have the following in my `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts")
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```

The font files are in the assets/font directory, and the SCSS file has this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?') %>');
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') %>') format('embedded-opentype'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff') %>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf') %>') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Has anyone run into similar issues? (Most posts that I've read either show boxes which is not the problem, or they revolve around issue with the font not working in Firefox.)

Comment: Can you show the site? Do you get 404's on the fonts or are they found ok?

Comment: I don't get 404s, they seem to be found ok. I can't show the site because it's in dev mode...

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a bit more output. Troubleshooting this, I'd first be looking at the code your Ruby app puts out, rather than the code for the app itself.

Comment: where is your font-awesome.min.css

Comment: I'm running into a similar problem, did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: Fix was simple as adding <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> to top of head tag

Answer (score 0):

Include this in your header file

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css"
```

For IE7 Support pls add

```
 link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/font-awesome.min.css"
 !--[if IE 7] 
 link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome-ie7.min.css"
 ![endif]--
```

What are you are using less or scss for your css ?

Comment: I'm using scss. I'm not adding stylesheets manually to the header, the assets pipeline in Rails takes care of that